# How does the full derivative of softmax + cross entropy have the correct dimensions?

Tags: neural-networks, derivative, softmax, gradient, jacobian

The blog post [the softmax function and its derivative](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative/) explains the following:

- Imagine that each input has $N$ features / pixels / etc.
- Imagine each input can be classified into $C$ classes
- Let the weights be $W$. The weights will have dimension $N$ by $C$.

  - Each column are the weights for a single class

We know that $W \cdot x$, where $x$ is the input will produce a vector of size $C$, which will the logits. One for each class.

The soft max function takes in a vector of logits and spits out another vector of normalized probabilities.

So, the soft max function takes in a vector of length $C$ and outputs another vector of length $C$.

Thus, the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the soft max function is of size $C$ x $C$.

The next question is: What is the Jacobian matrix of $W \cdot x$. Well, the answer is $C$ by $NC$. Roughly, this makes sense. There are $C$ logits. And each logit has a partial derivative with respect to every element in the matrix, $W$, there are a total of $NC$ elements in $W$.

Now, we just need to multiply the 2 matrices together to get the derivative of softmax + cross entropy with respect to $W$.

However, if we multiply the matrices together, we get a new matrix of size $C$ by $NC$. This is also confirmed in the blog post.

My issue is that the weights matrix is of size $N$ by $C$. So the dimensions do not match.
What am I missing?